# Is there a name for the distribution of this CDF function?

Tags: probability

CDF: $F(x) = (1-e^{-a \cdot x^2})^{\frac{b}{c-x}}$

where $a,b,c$ are positive constants, and $x \geq 0$.

Can any body give some advice on how to analyze the mean, variance or any other properties of the distribution?

Answer (score 1):

While I have not seen the distribution before, from the CDF, we can find the probability density function. I have to admit that I have to use *Mathematica* to find this.

$$\frac{d}{dx}(F(x))=f(x)=F(x)\left[\dfrac{2ab\cdot x\cdot e^{-ax^2}}{(1-e^{-ax^2})(c-x)}+\dfrac{b\ln(1-e^{-ax^2})}{(c-x)^2}\right]$$

$$E(X)=\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx \quad \text{I was not able to compute this}$$

$$Var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2=\int_0^\infty x^2 f(x)dx-\left(\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx\right)^2$$

***However***, I was able to calculate 
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$$
assuming $a=b=c=1$. This integral in fact **does not** converge, which it should and precisely to $1$ by definition of a probability distribution. Thus, there is strong reason to believe that this is not an actual probability distribution.

Comment: It is strange. Cause $F(\infty) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Graphing $F(x)$, it blows up at $x=c$ and/or at $x=0$.

For CDF, $F(x)$ should also be continuous and monotonic increasing.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot that.